RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time on loss tensor
I have the following training code. I am quite sure I call loss.backward() just once, and yet I am getting the error from the title. What am I doing wrong? Note that the X_train_tensor is output from another graph calculation, so it has required_grad=True as you can see in the print statement. Is this the source of the problem, and if so, how can I change it? It won't allow me to toggle it directly on the tensor.
for iter in range(max_iters):
start_ix = 0
loss = None

while start_ix < len(X_train_tensor):
    loss = None
    end_ix = min(start_ix + batch_size, len(X_train_tensor))
    out, loss, accuracy = model(X_train_tensor[start_ix:end_ix], y_train_tensor[start_ix:end_ix])

    # every once in a while evaluate the loss on train and val sets
    if (start_ix==0) and (iter % 10 == 0 or iter == max_iters - 1):
        out_val, loss_val, accuracy_val = model(X_val_tensor, y_val_tensor)
        print(f"step {iter}: train loss={loss:.2f} train_acc={accuracy:.3f} | val loss={loss_val:.2f} val_acc={accuracy_val:.3f}  {datetime.datetime.now()}")


    optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
    print (iter, start_ix, X_train_tensor.requires_grad, y_train_tensor.requires_grad, loss.requires_grad)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    start_ix = end_ix + 1

This is the error:
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

Update: this is where the model input tensors are coming from, as output of other (autoencoder) model:
autoencoder.eval()
with torch.no_grad(): # it seems like adding this line solves the problem?
    X_train_encoded, loss = autoencoder(X_train_tensor)
    X_val_encoded, loss = autoencoder(X_val_tensor)
    X_test_encoded, loss = autoencoder(X_test_tensor)

Adding the with torch.no_grad() line above solves the issue, but I don't understand why. Does it actually change how the outputs are generated, how does that work?

From what I understand, the X_train_tensor is output from the autoencoder. When you do not run torch.no_grad() during the encoding step, a computational graph is created for the outputs of the autoencoder, which links the autoencoder's operations and weights to the encoded tensors. In your code, since the model's output uses the X_train_tensor, the model's loss is connected to the autoencoder's computational graph.
When you call loss.backward() the first time, PyTorch traverses the entire computational graph, including the autoencoder, to compute gradients and then clears the graph. When you call loss.backward() in the second iteration of the loop, you are attempting to traverse the cleared autoencoder's computational graph.
torch.no_grad() prevents PyTorch from creating the autoencoder computational graph or linking the resulting loss to the autoencoder.

Interesting. How about if I deleted the autoencoder object or set it to None, would that have worked?

It's hard to say without more code, but this is what I think is happening:
The full X_train_tensor has requires_grad=True. Each iteration you take a slice defined by X_train_tensor[start_ix:end_ix], run it through the model, and compute the grad.
When you backprop your loss, it backprops into X_train_tensor since requires_grad=True. You only process a slice of the tensor, but autograd calculates the gradient for the entire X_train_tensor (all values not in the slice are zero as they did not get used in the loss calculation).
When you do the next iteration, X_train_tensor already has a grad, so you get the "Trying to backward through the graph a second time" error.
If it's not important to compute the gradient of X_train_tensor, you can fix this easily by calling detach on the tensor - ie X_train_tensor = X_train_tensor.detach().
